# Non-linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am trying to solve this differential equation which popped up in an engineering problem.

\begin{align}
&a\dot{V}(t) + b P(t) &= x(t)\\
&V(t)P(t) &= y(t)
\end{align}

The values $a$ and $b$ are known constants and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are known functions.  We are asked to find $V(t)$ and $P(t)$.
The equation was more complicated in the beginning and this is as much as I managed to simplify it, however  I am stuck at this point, and I haven't solved differential equations in a while.

It's not hard to reduce this to
$$
\frac{x(t)}{b}V(t) - \frac{a}{b}V(t)\dot{V}(t) = y(t)
$$
But this is non-linear and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Using different letters for the constant and the functions would be much better.

Comment: Your last equation doesn't seem to follow from your first two. Should the functions $a(t), b(t)$ be different?

Comment: I updated the question. The functions are renamed to $x(t),y(t)$ and now the last equation follows from the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODE is an Abel equation of the second kind. Here's a resource for finding your solution!
http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0125.pdf